# How to bypass a blocked port on a server through tunneling?

Tags: ssh, firewall, tunneling

I have installed trac bug tracker on a server behind firewall. I can access it through 127.0.0.1:8000 within the server. I am accessing the server using putty. Now, I would like to access the trac site through my machine, however port 8000 is blocked. How do I access the trac site from my machine through port 22.

Thanks!!

Comment: This question is not clear enough. What does "blocked" mean? Is the server behind a firewall? Behind a router? Is port 22 open? If so, what's listening on port 22? SSH? Are you sure port 8000 is open? What's the public IP of "localhost" / from where do you try to access it? Please do not leave all this to guesses from readers.

Comment: @DanielS. Hope this clears it up.

Comment: Question might not be formulated that well - but I think one can understand it... So why the downrating?

Comment: At first, it was formulated badly. And maybe others think that googling for "putty tunnel" would help more quickly than asking a question here.

Comment: @DanielS. Thanks for the answer. It worked. I wonder why it is deleted. Besides, there is an assumption of prior knowledge of both tunneling and putty to be able to use the precise search strings you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this screenshot:
[image]

Put in 8000 for the portnumbers and put in localhost instead of mail.tralala.org . That will do it. Then you can connect from your local PC to "localhost:8000" and you will end up connecting to your trac server at port 8000.

Do not forget to click the Add button.

Comment: Btw.: If I am not completely wrong, this version of Putty is quite a little older ;)